# Data binding to a UserControl in a FormView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a `FormView` that contains a custom UserControl, but I can't seem to databind my UserControl to the data item. Data binding to other built-in ASP.NET controls works fine.

Here's a quick example:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Works: Binding a Label's 'Text' property -->
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%# Item.ToString() %>" />

        <!-- Works: Setting my custom control's 'Text' property in markup -->
        <my:CustomControl runat="server" Text="plain text in markup" />

        <!-- DOESN'T WORK: Binding my custom control's 'Text' property -->
        <my:CustomControl runat="server" Text="<%# Item.ToString() %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

The first two controls display correctly; the last example is blank and setting a breakpoint in the `Text` property reveals it's never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use Eval instead it should work, try the below:

```
<my:CustomControl runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("Item") %>" />
```